# How to get name of object send in function vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My question is simple, but could not find the answer. maybe because it doesn't exists, but we will see.

My question is the following:

I made a global prototype in vue. (basically a global class) that has a function in it. I send my object in it. If i try to get the name of that object... i can't....

code:

```js
// index.vue
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      portfolio: {
        portfolioID: null
      }
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    // set model to new data                 // send old model
    this.portfolio = await this.$content.get(this.portfolio)
  }
}

// other file
export default class Content {
    static async get(content_type) {
        if (typeof content_type == 'object') {
            // [need to get the output of `portfolio`] out of the
            // content_type object
        }
        else { return { message: 'Input needs to be a model' } }
    }
}
```

> I don't want the keys of the portfolio object.
>   I want the output of 'portfolio' in the content class get function

my response now in the get function from the content_type object:

```
{
   portfolioID
}
```

but my expectations are:

```
portfolio: {
  portfolioID
}
```

or at least get the 'portfolio' name

Comment: i edited my question now so you can see what i mean

Comment: pass {[keyname]:this[keyname]} or {portfolio: this.portfolio}

Comment: thnx is there a easier way to do this in vue? i want to get the name, but if i can not change my input. is that possible?

Comment: i think i would make this a mixin with a property like keyname - in in those ones i need it i would set the keyname = "porfolio or we" - but its more a design decision

Comment: thnx a lot for the help. but i didn't worked a lot with mixins. can you make a demo in codepen or something like that?

Comment: if you want all the data object just use `this.$data`.

Answer (score 0):

> can you make a demo in codepen or something like that?

```
let importedComponent= (keyname)=> ({
  async mounted() {
    if(keyname in this)
      this[keyname] = await this.$content.get({[keyname]: this[keyname])
    else throw()
  }
})

export default {
  mixin: [
    importedComponent("portfolio")
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      portfolio: {
        portfolioID: null
      } 
    }
  },

}
```

Comment: thnx a lot. but that's not what i'm aming for. still helpfull tho!!